# Print 2D array names and grades

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

My project needs me to add names then grades, alternating between each person per assignment. So I enter the number of students, then the number of assignments, the students names, then their grades.

My problem is my print function is printing the grades straight down in a column instead of printing in rows.  I think I'm missing something, my print function is called print_report.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int numStus;
int numGrades;

// Get students names
void get_students(char stuNames[numStus][10])
{
  int i;
  int j;

  for (i=0; i<numStus; i++)
  {
    printf("Enter the students name.");
    scanf("%s", &stuNames[i]);
  }
}

// enter each students grades
void get_grades(int grades[numGrades][numStus], char stuNames[numStus]    [10])
{
  int x;
  int z;

  for (x=0; x < numGrades; x++)
  {
    for (z = 0; z < numStus; z++)
    {
      printf("Enter score for %s assignment %d:  ", stuNames[z],x);
      scanf("%d", &grades[x][z]);
    }
  }
}

void calc_grades( );
void print_report(int grades[numGrades][numStus], char stuNames[numStus] [10])
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;

  for(i = 0; i < numStus; i++)
  {
    printf("%s   ",stuNames[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  for(j = 0; j < numGrades; j++)
  {
    for(k = 0; k < numStus; k++)
    {
      printf("%6i",grades[j][k] );
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  printf("How many students?");
  scanf("%d", &numStus);
  printf("How many assignments?");
  scanf("%d", &numGrades);

  // Ask how many students

  // Ask how many assignments

  // Initializations...
  char stuNames[numStus][10];
  int grades[numGrades][numStus];
  char finalGrades[numStus];

  //Get Student Names
  get_students(stuNames);
  get_grades(grades, stuNames);
  print_report(grades, stuNames);

  int x;
  int z;

  // Get Grades

  // Calculate Final Grades

  // Print Report

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what you expect result ?

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is look at your print_report function. Move the printf("\n") statement outside the nested for loop to the outer for loop. Like this:

```
for(j = 0; j < numGrades; j++)
{
    for(k = 0; k < numStus; k++)
    {
    printf("%6i",grades[j][k] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am not sure if this is the problem that you were having, but my intuition tells me that it is.